# Python script running in pycharm but not in cmd

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm

I use Pycharm with python version 3.9 and scripts run just fine,
but when I write `python` in cmd, it opens Microsoft Store on the page of Python3.10.
Do I need to give cmd some kind of premission to python? How do I do that?

I searched online, but I couldn't find a way to make cmd run python without downloading it again.

edit: I want to use cmd as a terminal and to be able to run scripts through it.
In order to use cmd as python terminal I write `python` but cmd can't find it.
This is the location/path of python:
C:\Users\ofira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe

Comment: Please explain what exactly you're running and what is the command that you're running your script with.

Comment: it might to define `Environment Variable ` and make clear where your `python` path is

Answer (score 1):

The solution is easy. When the microsoft store open's type python3.9 in the search tab. Download it and everything will work like a charm. Downloading it form the store will automatically add the path in the system environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I can't write a comment because my reputation is still low, but I was wondering if you were using Pycharm with an interpreter bundled with something like Anaconda (I did and I got the same problem as yours).

If this is the case, I solved it downloading the latest version of python from python.org (like [this one](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.3/python-3.11.3-amd64.exe)) and proceeding with the installation.
You should be able to type `python` on your prompt and run the interpreter with no effort.
Also, you can choose this new interpreter on Pycharm as well (just go on the lower right corner of the IDE and select it).

[image: Right here]